# dynamic pricing and request a quote woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, class, woocommerce

## Hello World!

I am currently working on an e-commerce website based on woocommerce and I've recently bought

> the Dynamic Pricing & the Request a Quote plugins made by [YITH](https://yithemes.com/)

Everything is okay with those plugins but the e-commerce website I'm doing can both do quote and cart that's why I use the Request a Quote plugin but the differents dynamic prices I do are'nt visibe in my Quote page but they are in my cart page.

After many search on google it seems that the two plugins are not compatible.

> #### So this is my question, is there a way to hook the final prices obtain by the dynamic prices plugin in my quote page ?

I know some basics on PHP and I have took a look at the differents functions and classes of the both plugins to try to solve the problem but I didn't found it.. :(

Here is the beta of website i'm doing, [http://beta.jardivrac.com](http://beta.jardivrac.com/produit/bleu/) you can try the dynamic prices on this page and after go to the card page and the quote page

And here is the public function I've found on the fronted class in the dynamic prices plugin ->

```
public function replace_cart_item_price( $price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {

        if ( ! isset( $cart_item['ywdpd_discounts'] ) ) {
            return $price;
        }
        $old_price = $price;

        foreach ( $cart_item['ywdpd_discounts'] as $discount ) {
            if ( isset( $discount['status'] ) && $discount['status'] == 'applied' ) {

                if ( wc_price( $cart_item['ywdpd_discounts']['default_price'] ) != WC()->cart->get_product_price( $cart_item['data'] ) ) {
                    $price = '<del>' . wc_price( $cart_item['ywdpd_discounts']['default_price'] ) . '</del> ' . WC()->cart->get_product_price( $cart_item['data'] );
                } else {
                    return $price;
                }
            }
        }

        $price = apply_filters( 'ywdpd_replace_cart_item_price', $price, $old_price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

        return $price;
    }
```

If somebody have the solution that will be a great news !

Thanks in advance for your help !

Antoine

> EDIT:
>
> This is the loop inside the Woocommerce cart.php

```
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $_product   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
        $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

        if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
            $product_permalink = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', $_product->is_visible() ? $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) : '', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
            ?>
            <tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">

                <td class="product-remove">
                    <?php
                        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf(
                            '<a href="%s" class="remove" title="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s">&times;</a>',
                            esc_url( WC()->cart->get_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
                            __( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
                            esc_attr( $product_id ),
                            esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
                        ), $cart_item_key );
                    ?>
                </td>

                <td class="product-thumbnail">
                    <?php
                        $thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                        if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
                            echo $thumbnail;
                        } else {
                            printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $thumbnail );
                        }
                    ?>
                </td>

                <td class="product-name" data-title="<?php _e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                    <?php
                        if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
                            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_title(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) . '&nbsp;';
                        } else {
                            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $_product->get_title() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                        }

                        // Meta data
                        echo WC()->cart->get_item_data( $cart_item );

                        // Backorder notification
                        if ( $_product->backorders_require_notification() && $_product->is_on_backorder( $cart_item['quantity'] ) ) {
                            echo '<p class="backorder_notification">' . esc_html__( 'Available on backorder', 'woocommerce' ) . '</p>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </td>

                <td class="product-price" data-title="<?php _e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                    <?php
                        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                    ?>
                </td>

                <td class="product-quantity" data-title="<?php _e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                    <?php
                        if ( $_product->is_sold_individually() ) {
                            $product_quantity = sprintf( '1 <input type="hidden" name="cart[%s][qty]" value="1" />', $cart_item_key );
                        } else {
                            $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
                                'input_name'  => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
                                'input_value' => $cart_item['quantity'],
                                'max_value'   => $_product->backorders_allowed() ? '' : $_product->get_stock_quantity(),
                                'min_value'   => '0'
                            ), $_product, false );
                        }

                        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item );
                    ?>
                </td>

                <td class="product-subtotal" data-title="<?php _e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                    <?php
                        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $cart_item['quantity'] ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    }
```

> And this is the loop for the quote

```
$total = 0;
            foreach ( $raq_content as $key => $raq ):

            $_product = wc_get_product( ( isset( $raq['variation_id'] ) && $raq['variation_id'] != '' ) ? $raq['variation_id'] : $raq['product_id'] );

            if( ! $_product ){
                continue;
            }

            $show_price = true;


            do_action( 'ywraq_before_request_quote_view_item', $raq_content, $key );
            ?>
            <tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'yith_ywraq_item_class', 'cart_item', $raq_content, $key ) ); ?>" <?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'yith_ywraq_item_attributes', '', $raq_content, $key ) ); ?>>

                <td class="product-remove">
                    <?php
                    echo apply_filters( 'yith_ywraq_item_remove_link', sprintf( '<a href="#"  data-remove-item="%s" data-wp_nonce="%s"  data-product_id="%d" class="yith-ywraq-item-remove remove" title="%s">&times;</a>', $key, wp_create_nonce( 'remove-request-quote-' . $_product->id ), $_product->id, __( 'Retirer cet article', 'yith-woocommerce-request-a-quote' ) ), $key );
                    ?>

                </td>

                <td class="product-thumbnail">
                    <?php $thumbnail = $_product->get_image();

                    if ( ! $_product->is_visible() ) {
                        echo $thumbnail;
                    } else {
                        printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', $_product->get_permalink(), $thumbnail );
                    }
                    ?>
                </td>

                <td class="product-name">
                    <?php
                    $title = $_product->get_title();

                    if ( $_product->get_sku() != '' && get_option( 'ywraq_show_sku' ) == 'yes' ) {
                        $title .= apply_filters( 'ywraq_sku_label', __( ' SKU:', 'yith-woocommerce-request-a-quote' ) ) . $_product->get_sku();
                    }
                    ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->get_permalink() ?>"><?php echo $title ?></a>
                    <?php
                    // Meta data

                    $item_data = array();

                    // Variation data
                    if ( ! empty( $raq['variation_id'] ) && is_array( $raq['variations'] ) ) {

                        foreach ( $raq['variations'] as $name => $value ) {
                            $label = '';

                            if ( '' === $value ) {
                                continue;
                            }

                            $taxonomy = wc_attribute_taxonomy_name( str_replace( 'attribute_pa_', '', urldecode( $name ) ) );

                            // If this is a term slug, get the term's nice name
                            if ( taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) ) {
                                $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $value, $taxonomy );
                                if ( ! is_wp_error( $term ) && $term && $term->name ) {
                                    $value = $term->name;
                                }
                                $label = wc_attribute_label( $taxonomy );

                            } else {

                                if ( strpos( $name, 'attribute_' ) !== false ) {
                                    $custom_att = str_replace( 'attribute_', '', $name );

                                    if ( $custom_att != '' ) {
                                        $label = wc_attribute_label( $custom_att );
                                    } else {
                                        $label = $name;
                                    }
                                }

                            }

                            $item_data[] = array(
                                'key'   => $label,
                                'value' => $value
                            );
                        }
                    }

                    $item_data = apply_filters( 'ywraq_request_quote_view_item_data', $item_data, $raq, $_product, $show_price );


                    // Output flat or in list format
                    if ( sizeof( $item_data ) > 0 ) {
                        foreach ( $item_data as $data ) {
                            echo esc_html( $data['key'] ) . ': ' . wp_kses_post( $data['value'] ) . "\n";
                        }
                    }


                    ?>
                </td>
                
                <td class="product-price" data-title="<?php _e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                    <?php
                        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                    ?>
                </td>


                <td class="product-quantity">
                    <?php
                    $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
                        'input_name'  => "raq[{$key}][qty]",
                        'input_value' => apply_filters( 'ywraq_quantity_input_value', $raq['quantity'] ),
                        'max_value'   => apply_filters( 'ywraq_quantity_max_value', $_product->backorders_allowed() ? '' : $_product->get_stock_quantity(), $_product ),
                        'min_value'   => apply_filters( 'ywraq_quantity_min_value', 0, $_product )
                    ), $_product, false );

                    echo $product_quantity;
                    ?>
                </td>

                <?php if ( get_option( 'ywraq_hide_total_column', 'yes' ) == 'no' ): ?>
                    <td class="product-subtotal">
                        <?php
                            $total += apply_filters( 'yith_ywraq_product_price', $_product->get_display_price( '', $raq[ 'quantity' ] ), $_product, $raq );
                            $price = apply_filters( 'yith_ywraq_product_price_html', WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $raq[ 'quantity' ] ), $_product, $raq );
                            echo apply_filters( 'yith_ywraq_hide_price_template', $price, $_product->id, $raq);
                        ?>
                    </td>
                <?php endif ?>
            </tr>
            <?php do_action( 'ywraq_after_request_quote_view_item', $raq_content, $key ); ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        <!--
            <?php if ( get_option( 'ywraq_hide_total_column', 'yes' ) == 'no' ): ?>
            <tr>
                <td  colspan="3">
                </td>
                <th>
                    <?php _e( 'Total:', 'yith-woocommerce-request-a-quote') ?>
                </th>
                <td class="raq-totals">
                    <?php echo wc_price( $total ); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php endif ?>
            -->
```

I think it will help, I already tried to replace the loop of the request a quote page by the loop of the card but it only created 2 cart loop, not what I expected... Maybe somebody better in PHP than me could have an idea ?

Comment: Note: Your question is complicated, as your issue is a real development affair. The problem is when using some plugins as YITH ones (here in this case), that are helping you to change/add some functionalities/behaviors in one hand, will also oblige you in the other hand to stay in that predefined changes/behaviors. Most of the time they don't provide a correct way to get extended, and you should need to add some custom changes inside the plugin files to get them work together with other ones (or with custom code). **May be you will have to write your own plugin to get that work as you expect**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## After many try & a short night I've found a "solution" not really good one, but everything works perfectly!

So I modified those pages:

> *request-quote-view.php* (Table of the quote page)

I've added this little loop before the foreach of the differents products in the table.

```
$arr_discount = array();
foreach(YITH_WC_Dynamic_Pricing() as $key => $raq ){
    foreach($raq as $arr => $data){
        array_push($arr_discount, $data);
    }
}
```

With this loop I put the differents informations about the dynamic pricing in a new array

So then, in the start of the foreach loop I have an other loop wich put the content we get before into the array of the quote

```
foreach($arr_discount as $test){
    foreach($test['apply_to_products_list'] as $id){
        if($id == $raq['product_id']){
            foreach($test['rules'] as $rule){
                $raq['arr_dsct'][] = $rule;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finaly in the *td class=subtotal* I replaced the content with

```
if(isset($raq['arr_dsct']) == ''){
    $total += apply_filters( 'yith_ywraq_product_price', $_product->get_display_price( '', $raq[ 'quantity' ] ), $_product, $raq );
    $price = apply_filters( 'yith_ywraq_product_price_html', WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $raq[ 'quantity' ] ), $_product, $raq );
    echo apply_filters( 'yith_ywraq_hide_price_template', $price, $_product->id, $raq); 
} else {
    $count = count($raq['arr_dsct']);
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        if( $raq['quantity'] >= $raq['arr_dsct'][$i][min_quantity] AND $raq['quantity'] <= $raq['arr_dsct'][$i][max_quantity] ){
            $price = $_product->price - $_product->price * $raq['arr_dsct'][$i][discount_amount];
            $total = round($raq['quantity'] * $price, 2);
            $totale = '<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">'. $total .'<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></span>';
        } elseif ( $raq['quantity'] < $raq['arr_dsct'][0][min_quantity] ) {
            $total += apply_filters( 'yith_ywraq_product_price', $_product->get_display_price( '', $raq[ 'quantity' ] ), $_product, $raq );
            $price = apply_filters( 'yith_ywraq_product_price_html', WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $raq[ 'quantity' ] ), $_product, $raq );
            $totale = apply_filters( 'yith_ywraq_hide_price_template', $price, $_product->id, $raq); 
        }
    }
    echo $totale;
}
```

> request-quote-table.php (Table of the mail)

For the mail page it was exactly the same answer with only one difference, the array object of the product is named *$item* not *$raq* so It need some modification

#### If you want more information about the place where should be the different piece of code there is two images wich show it !

[image]

[image]